# How can I center the text in a table?

Tags: html, css

I have a table and I wanted to use the vertical-align but it's not working. I can get the size of the number to mach the size of the images, so maybe that is why I can't use it. please help.

http://jsfiddle.net/d7onugrw/1/

```css
td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="tel:+56966890434">(56-9) 6689 04 34</a>

    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://plus.google.com/111125806825828710565" rel="publisher">
        <img alt="google" src="http://www.claudiacabrera.cl/images/google.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Pintura-Claudia-Cabrera">
        <img alt="facebook" src="http://www.claudiacabrera.cl/images/facebook.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=176837064&trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile_pic">
        <img alt="linked in" src="http://www.claudiacabrera.cl/images/linkedin.png" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this, it changes the way layouts are performed. You want it to lay out like a table cell, not a floating element:

```
float:left;
```

Remove this, it changes the way layouts are performed. You want it to lay out like a table cell, not a block element:

```
display:block;
```

Remove this, table cells automatically fill their row (unless they have `rowspan`).

```
height:100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you floating the elements? Floated elements don't obey to `vertical-align` property

Remove `float: left` and `display: block` and you get the content vertical aligned.

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d7onugrw/4/)